# How can I transfer multiple rows of a tableView to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to add a feature in my app, to add multiple members to one action at one time. The members are listed in a `tableView` and the user can select multiple rows at one time with the `.allowsMultipleSelection = true` function. I got the following code but this doesn't work. I think my idea would work but not in the way I have it in the code :

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddMultipleMemberTransactionViewController,
        let selectedRows = multipleMemberTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else  {
            return
        }
        destination.members = members[selectedRows]
    }
```

Does somebody out here know, how I can solve this problem, because there is an error :

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[Member?]' with an index of type '[IndexPath]'

I have the same feature in the app but just for one member. There I in the let `selectedRows` line after the `indexPathForSelectedRow` a .row. Is there a similar function for `indexPathsForSelectedRows` ?
Or is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: `selectedRows` is a an array of IndexPath. You can't do `members[ArrayOfIndexPath]`. How do you use the indexPathes in cellForRowAtItem? Then we can think on how to retrieve only the objects at selected indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
destination.members = selectedRows.map{ members[$0.row] }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the indexPathsForSelectedRows indicates, it returns an array of IndexPath.  What you need to do is create an array of Member objects based on those path.

Assuming you have a "members" array that contain all the members the user can select from, and your table has only 1 section:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   var selectedMembers: [Member] = []
   guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddMultipleMemberTransactionViewController,
    let selectedIndexes = multipleMemberTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else  {
        return
    }
    for selectedIndex in selectedIndexes {
      let selectedMember = members[selectedIndex.row]
      selectedMembers.append(selectedMember)
    }
    destination.members = selectedMembers
}
```

You can also use the array map() function to change the for loop into a single line operation:

```
let selectedMembers: [Member] = selectedRows.map{ members[$0.row] }
```

Both should effectively do the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer worked too. But as the answer of Sh_Khan was the first which worked I think I have to accept his answer. I really appreciate your help too.